# Dual space of Bochner space: is there an easier proof to show they're isometric?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

It is known that $[L^p(0,T;H)]^* = L^q(0,T;H^*)$.

If $p=q=2$ and $H$ is a Hilbert space, is there an easier proof to show that the spaces are **isometric**? The proof that I know for the general case uses some sort of epsilon argument, but there must be an easier way when we have access to Riesz maps?

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130857/proof-that-l20-tx-l20-tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, I might be underestimating the problem, but I believe that if $H$ is a Hilbert space, then so is $L^2(0,T;H)$. Isometry then follows directly from Riesz Representation Theorem.

Comment: No, this is all there is to it.  I wonder why this question has hung around for four days. I just voted to close.