# Dual of $L^2(0,T,C)$ where $C'=BD(\Omega)$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Here is the hypothesis of my problem : $T>0$, $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a regular boundary. I'm actually looking for a proof that explains what is the dual of $L^2(0,T,C)$ where $C'=BD(\Omega)$ (ie the dual of $C$ is the space $BD$ and $BD(\Omega)$ the space of bounded deformation (functions in $L^1(\Omega)$ with symmetric gradient in $M_1(\Omega)$ (space of bounded measures)).

Thank you

EDIT : If $C$ is separable, then I know (theorem 2.112 page 224 from the book Modern methods in the Calculus of Variations : $L^p$ space (by Fonseca and Leoni and edited by Springer-Verlag) ) that we can say that if $L\in L^2(0,T;C)'$ then there exists a unique $v\in L^2_{w}(0,T;BD(\Omega))$ such that 
$$\forall u\in L^2(0,T;C), L(u)=\int_0^T \left(u,v \right)_{C,BD(\Omega)} dt$$

where $L^2_{w}(0,T;BD(\Omega))$ is the space of weakly-star measurable function $u$ (ie $t\mapsto (y,u(t))_{C,BD(\Omega)}$ is measurable for every $y\in C$) such that $\left\| u\right\|_{BD(\Omega)}\in L^2(0,T)$. I've seen this result (without any mention of the hypothesis of separability), so the question is now : is $C$ a separable space (for the exact definition of $C$, see comments).

Comment: What is $C$ ? In R. E. Edwards' book *Functional Analysis*, it is shown that under suitable conditions the dual of $F=L^p(\mu,E)$ is represented by a suitably defined space $L^{p'}(\mu,E_\sigma')$. So the dual of $F$ is not necessarily uniquely determined by the strong dual of $E$, and it may depend on $E$ itself.

Comment: Pietro, you should undelete your deleted answer because Martin provided an answer in his comment to your answer.

Comment: Might be relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130857/proof-that-l20-tx-l20-tx/130865#130865

Comment: @AndrásBátkai Thank you for the reference but I've already looked this book and I don't know if $BD(\Omega)$ has the Radon-Nikodym property with respect to the Lebesgue measure. By the way, $BD(\Omega)$ is a non-reflexive and non-separable space.

Comment: @TaQ In Energy methods in finite element analysis, G.Strang, H. Matthies and E. Christiansen prove that the predual of $BD(\Omega)$ (denoted by $C$ here) is the space of function $g=\text{div} M$ where $M$ is a continuous (on $\overline{\Omega}$) symmetric matrix.

Comment: @ user37238: I do not understand what precisely you intend the spaces $C$ and BD$(\Omega)$ to be, but if $C$ is a separable Banach space then Edwards' theorem (somewhere around pages 590−600) covers your case.

Comment: @TaQ To be totally clear, here is a definition of the space $BD(\Omega)$. $BD(\Omega)= \left\{ u\in L^1(\Omega)^n,\ \forall 1\le i,j\le n,\ \partial_i u_j + \partial_j u_i \in M^1(\Omega) \right\}$ where $M^1(\Omega)$ is the space of bounded measure and $u_i$ is the $i$-th component of $u$.

Comment: The previous definition does not depend on the orthonormal basis that we choose for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @ user37238: As I suggested in my previous comments, it would be more important to know the space $C$. If it is a separable Banach space, then look at Edwards' book. If it is not Banach, or is Banach but is neither reflexive (which I understand it not to be in view of the information you have given) nor separable, then to my knowledge there is no general result which would be helpfull here unless you somehow manage to apply the Diestel Uhl result András Bátkai has given.

Comment: @TaQ Ok thank you anyway. I don't know much about the space $C$. Everywhere I've read about $BD(\Omega)$, people say that $BD(\Omega)$ is the dual of a Banach space (no more, no description of this Banach space except in Strang-Matthies-Christiansen).

Comment: @ user37238: "is $C$ a separable space (for the exact definition of $C$, see comments)." In one comment, you say that $C$ is "the space of function $g={\rm div\kern.5mm}M$ where $M$ is a continuous (on $\overline Ω$) symmetric matrix". This does not at all specify the space $C$. To give it precisely, you should at least answer to the following questions: (1) Do you mean that $M$ is or can be extended to be a continuous function $\overline Ω\to{\rm SM\kern.5mm}(n)$ where ${\rm SM\kern.5mm}(n)$ is the finite-dimensional space of real (or complex?) symmetric $n\times n$ matrices? (cont.)

Comment: (2) If you answer "yes" to (1), then how precisely you define $g={\rm div\kern.5mm}M$ ? I guess it is some kind of distribution on $\Omega$ with values in $\mathbb R^{\kern.5mm n}$. How is it normed, i.e. what is $\|g\|$ ?